# Encrypting a properties file of a Webserver (AES)

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am currently developing an Android app that requests specific properties from my webserver, which look like this:

```
<properties>
<property name="Approved-IP" value="SomeIPAddresses"/>
</properties>
```

The app saves the site as a temporary XML file and tries to check these IPs.
I want to let the server encrypt the properties using AES and IF the app doesn't have an encryption password set use a default key like "test123".

The app then decrypts this information via the EasyCrypt library and uses it.

The problem is that I don't really know how to do it server-side, so that the information won't be passed in plain text.

Comment: To avoid clear text in transit it is enough to use https. Your solution would not really be more secure because the key if embedded in the App is publicly available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for my program (beware, this is just for exercise, so I wouldn't call it safe in ANY way)

I am using this method to encrypt the String on my WebServer:

```
private static byte[] encrypt(String plain, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] clean = plain.getBytes();

    int ivSize = 16;
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clean);

    byte[] encryptedIVAndText = new byte[ivSize + encrypted.length];
    System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedIVAndText, 0, ivSize);
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, encryptedIVAndText, ivSize, encrypted.length);

    return encryptedIVAndText;
}
```

Then I am encoding the generated String with Base64

> Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedString)

And return the Base64 String.

My App decodes the returned String using the getDecoder function and decrypts it with this method:

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] encryptedIvTextBytes, String key) throws Exception {
    int ivSize = 16;
    int keySize = 16;

    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
    System.arraycopy(encryptedIvTextBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    int encryptedSize = encryptedIvTextBytes.length - ivSize;
    byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedSize];
    System.arraycopy(encryptedIvTextBytes, ivSize, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedSize);

    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize];
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(key.getBytes());
    System.arraycopy(md.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipherDecrypt.doFinal(encryptedBytes);

    return new String(decrypted);
}
```

And the result is the normal properties file.